# How to get started with developing accessories for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iokit, eaaccessory

We want to develop iOS accessories which plug into the 30-pin dock connector. Is there a good starting point for beginners which talks about what can and what can't be done with the EAAccessory framework?

Apress has released a book in June 2010 talking about the EAAccessory framework. Is this still relevant, or has Apple intrudoced lots of new APIs since then? Are there other resources available?

Comment: Take a look at [this response](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/can-a-hobbyist-or-individual-apply-for-apples-mfi-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across a program on the Apple Developer site that might interest you:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/  Might be worth checking out as a starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately this program is only for large companies. They require that the company is established, has it's own lawyer, an office building, etc.

Comment: @SecretService-notreally - That's not entirely true. As I answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11809/5292 we're a very small company, yet we were enrolled in the MFi program without a problem. Unless you're developing for jailbroken devices only, you'll need to be MFi approved in order to build any 30-pin accessories for iOS devices.